# I have a SQL query which needs to be written output in a spefic format in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table whose structure is  `test(id , col1,col2)`

Now I want to have  the output of just `col1` and `col2` in combination .
e.g. data in table is -

[image]

output should be --> `a,b,c,d,e,f`

Comment: . . I think you have so modified the question that you have invalidated the answers.  I would suggest that you revert to an earlier version and accept one of the answers.  Then ask a *new* question.

Comment: Sorry buddy, I will "edit" your question to revert to the original. If you have a different question, ask it in a different thread - or add the new requirement to the original one. Don't make my answer look like I am a total lunatic (my output has nothing to do with your 100% changed requirement). Just so you know, if you edit it again, I will edit again back to the original version AND lock the question - so, don't even try.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation within `listagg`:

```
SQL> with test (id, col1, col2) as
  2    (select 1, 'a', 'b' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'c', 'd' from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'e', 'f' from dual
  5    )
  6  select listagg(col1 ||','|| col2, ',') within group (order by id) result
  7  from test;

RESULT
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
a,b,c,d,e,f

SQL>
```

Another option is to use `xmlagg` (if result exceeds 4000 characters, which is limit of `listagg`):

```
SQL> with test (id, col1, col2) as
  2    (select 1, 'a', 'b' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'c', 'd' from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'e', 'f' from dual
  5    )
  6  select rtrim (
  7            xmlagg (xmlelement (e, col1 || ',' || col2 || ',') order by id).extract (
  8               '//text()'),
  9            ', ') result_2
 10    from test;

RESULT_2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
a,b,c,d,e,f

SQL>
```

---

After you posted a new desired output, well - that's VERY different from where we started. It is a simple `UNION`:

```
SQL> select col1 result from test
  2  union
  3  select col2 from test;

RESULT
----------
a
b
c
d
e
f

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: but the table is big this is sample data

Comment: I know; query you'd run begins at line #6 as you already have the table. I used CTE (the WITH factoring clause) so that I wouldn't have to create a test table.

Comment: This can't be the correct answer - your result is different from what the OP requested. I checked the edits (there were many), but the "requested result" was not changed from the very beginning. To get what the OP wants, you need only one call to LISTAGG, aggregating over `col1 || ',' || col2`.

Comment: So true, @mathguy. Didn't pay attention. Thank you, fixed.

Comment: yeah thats the output I needed but one hting is if the result set is big its giving result of string concatenation is too long

Comment: Use XMLAGG instead; I added that example into the answer, have a look. By the way, what will you do with that long string? Where will you use it?

Comment: character string buffer too small  ora -19011,get the result as lob instead.

Comment: @Littlefoot --Actually I want to take all the tables names from this table and  create synonym on them in a SP

Comment: Perhaps it would be better if you fix sample data so that it makes sense. A, B, C, ... aren't really "table names" and I can't imagine what does that loooooong concatenated string have to do with creating synonyms. Try to explain it better which will help us help you. Please, do NOT post that as a comment - edit the original question you posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230577/discussion-between-neha-and-littlefoot).

Comment: That's UNION, it seems. I posted a new query to the bottom of the answer, have a look.

Comment: @Littlefoot I cant see the query you posted .  I was wondering if it can be done other than union. can you come to the chat room?

Comment: How come you can't see it? Refresh the page, if necessary. I can't chat.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hack that may work when the resulting string is too long, requiring a CLOB output. (A "hack" is a solution that is believed to be 100% correct, but uses certain tools in ways they weren't intended to be used.) The hack is to use `json_arrayagg`, and to "lie" to Oracle, stating that the input is `format json` so that no escaping is performed.

Since it uses json functions, it will only work in Oracle 12.1 and higher.

```
with
  prep (lst) as (
    select json_arrayagg(col1 || ',' || col2 format json
                         order by id returning clob)
    from   your_table
  )
select substr(lst, 2, length(lst) - 2) as result
from   prep
;
```

The last query is needed, because the json array will include a pair of square brackets (that is the json notation for an array). The `substr` function strips the first and the last character from the CLOB. I prefer this over `ltrim` and `rtrim`, because the strings in `col1` and `col2` may already contain brackets, and those should not be stripped; only the first and the last character (a [ and a ]) should be stripped form the json array.